# AJAX Get from a JSON Tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, tree

I'm just starting out with AJAX, trying to use JQuery's $.getJSON function (or any related, ie $.load(), $.ajax(), etc). I have a JSON file with a structure something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "user@domain.com",
        "password": "password"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "email": "one@two.com",
        "password": "password"
    }
]
```

How can I call a GET on this JSON file (let's call it users.json) for a user with a specific email? I thought it would be the second paramter in $.getJSON, but that seems to just return the whole tree.

Thanks!

Comment: you would need to parse through the variables on the client side in javascript, or make it so users.json is generated dynamically and only output the correct json for a particular user

Comment: You're displaying user passwords in plain sight in a JSON request? Why on earth would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - you can't do this directly with AJAX.  jQuery can extract portions of HTML and XML documents, but not JSON.

Easiest answer - retrieve the entire object (you have to, anyway) and use [jsonpath](https://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/) to get the structure you want

Longer answer - retrieve the entire object, and traverse it yourself to get the object you want

Best answer - make the email address a parameter to whatever script produces the json and have the server only return the data you want.

Comment: Have to agree with "best answer", although if OP doesn't control the JSON then it won't be an option.

Comment: Currently using Easiest answer, because I'm trying to do as much in JS as possible. And trying out jsonpath and JSONselect

Answer (score 1):

Once the JSON is parsed, you pass it to a callback function - then you can manipulate that array however you need.

You'll probably want some custom code:

```
$.getJSON(myURL, function(data) {
    /* data is an array of objects */
    for (var i=0, j=data.length; i<j; i++) {
        if (data[i].email === some_value) {
            /* do something with data[i] */
        };
    };
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: what do you mean, no built-in way?  There's always `Array.filter`

Comment: @Alnitak Well, OBVIOUSLY I didn't mean that one.... (According to MDN, [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) isn't available for IE8 and below, so it's not "always" usable in this case.)

Comment: for IE8, there's always shims (or the dustbin...)

Answer (score 1):

You can 1 of 2 things, loop through the array on the client side, or dynamically have users.json generated on each call (this assumes a backend server language like php)

**Using dynamically generated json file**

JS

```
$.ajax({
   url:"/users.json.php",
   data:{
      useremail:"someusersemail@here.com"
   }
   type:"POST",
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(userdata){
      //users data will be in userdata
      console.log(userdata.email);
   }
})
```

Server Script (assumes PHP): `users.json.php`

```
$email = $_POST['useremail'];

//get user data based on email
...

echo json_encode($userdata);
die;
```

generated json file should end up outputing something like

```
{"id": 1,"email": "user@domain.com","password": "password"}
```

**Loop Method: loop through the users array on client side**

```
$.ajax({
   url:"/users.json",
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(data){
      for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
         var user = data[i];
         if(user.email == "someemail@gmail.com") {
            //do what you need to with user data
         }
      }
   }
})
```