# Show what I am listening to on Spotify

Tags: javascript, php, spotify

I am using this plugin to enable me to display what I am currently listening to live on my website: https://github.com/derekmartinez18/Simple-Ajax-Spotify-Now-Playing

A piece of JavaScript will run on page load, which connects to the PHP which via API checks what I am listening to, grabs the title etc, if successful sends back to the JavaScript and displays via HTML.

I've echoed out what the PHP is getting and can see it's correctly grabbing all the recent songs, names etc. Therefore because nothing is appearing on the page maybe it's the JavaScript. I've pasted it below with pastebin link to php too.

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function get_spotify() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/Scripts/last.fm.php',
                        data: { request: 'true' },
                        success: function(reply) {
                            $('.now-playing').html("<p>" + reply + "</p>");
                        }
                    });
                }
                window.onload = get_spotify;
            </script>
```

Pastebin of PHP - http://pastebin.com/eZUH6BNU
A snippet of the API output which is being past over to the PHP (it's huge so didn't paste it all.):

```
{"recenttracks":{"track":[{"artist":{"#text":"LMFAO","mbid":"ed5d9086-e8cd-473a-b96c-d81ad6c98f0d"},}
```

Live Link - http://bit.ly/1ewTe8l

Comment: Specify the content type you are expecting `application/json`, and then you want to loop through the array you are getting back.

Comment: Any errors in the console? You can also check in the Net / Network tab of the developers tools what the exact response is.

Comment: No console errors. Here is a live link too actually - http://bit.ly/1ewTe8l

Comment: @HanletEscaño - Where? sorry still a little new.

Comment: @tokyodrift like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18985864/752527

Comment: @HanletEscaño The php script does not return `json` but a text so that will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the example you have given below your question, the problem is that there is no element with a class of `now-playing`.

Your page seems to have been cut short, perhaps due to an error, but the ajax request fires and in the console I can see the response (the url is actually echoed before that as well):

```
I am currently listening to 01. Circles Around The Sun by Dispatch on Spotify.
```

Adding a `<div class="now-playing"></div>` should do the trick.

**Edit:** Note that your key is visible in the response as you are echoing the url you are making a request to. It might be a good idea to change the key when you have solved your problem.

Comment: Literally only needed to add that Div, didn't realise. Thank you!